# Ripple CSS not displaying

Tags: html, css

I got a question. I tried to get inspired by a code pen using CSS. I've tried to convert it to CSS. But I don't understand why that does not work. Could you please explain this to me.

```
.border_image_style {
border-radius: 90px;
background: #ffffff38;
border: 4px solid #fff;
}

.circle_ripple {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border-radius: 50%;
animation: ripple 1s linear infinite;    
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(#ff4855, 0.3),
                0 0 0 1em rgba(#ff4855, 0.3),
                0 0 0 3em rgba(#ff4855, 0.3),
                0 0 0 5em rgba(#ff4855, 0.3);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1em rgba(#ff4855, 0.3),
                0 0 0 3em rgba(#ff4855, 0.3),
                0 0 0 5em rgba(#ff4855, 0.3),
                0 0 0 8em rgba(#ff4855, 0);
  }
}

<div class="circle_ripple">   
<img src="{{ user.userprofile.image.url }}" width="100px" height="100px" class="border_image_style">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rgba()` function expects four parameters, not two.

Replace this:

```
rgba(#ff4855, 0.3)
```

With that:

```
rgba(255, 72, 85, 0.3)
```

Comment: thanks a lot :) that helped to understand my mistake